# Fatal error when installing Siberian CMS zend

Tags: php, zend-framework

I try to install a CMS system with the name Siberian CMS. I have tried to install it a lot of times but I get this error again and again.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Config_Exception' with message 'parse_ini_file() has been disabled for security reasons' in /home/korsbjer/public_html/ww15/lib/Zend/Config/Ini.php:182 Stack trace: #0 /home/korsbjer/public_html/ww15/lib/Zend/Config/Ini.php(202): Zend_Config_Ini->_parseIniFile('/home/korsbjer/...') #1 /home/korsbjer/public_html/ww15/lib/Zend/Config/Ini.php(126): Zend_Config_Ini->_loadIniFile('/home/korsbjer/...') #2 /home/korsbjer/public_html/ww15/lib/Zend/Application.php(386): Zend_Config_Ini->__construct('/home/korsbjer/...', 'production') #3 /home/korsbjer/public_html/ww15/lib/Zend/Application.php(85): Zend_Application->_loadConfig('/home/korsbjer/...') #4 /home/korsbjer/public_html/ww15/index.php(37): Zend_Application->__construct('production', '/home/korsbjer/...') #5 {main} thrown in     /home/korsbjer/public_html/ww15/lib/Zend/Config/Ini.php on line 182
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tim's right, the `parse_ini_file()` function is disabled on your server, so Zend can't parse the app.ini file and starts Siberian.

If you have a root SSH access, you can edit your php.ini and and remove `parse_ini_file` from the `disable_functions` list.

You can find the correct php.ini path by executing this command:

`php --ini`

The interesting line is:

`Loaded Configuration File:         /path/to/php.ini`

You can also find the correct path by using `phpinfo()`. But since `parse_ini_file()` is disabled, I don't have much hope on `phpinfo()`, it may be as well.

Once it's done, don't forget to restart Apache or PHP-FPM (it may be required, depends on how you use PHP).

Answer (score 0):

Zend Framework 1 uses ini files for configuration, as it seems does the CMS you are trying to install. PHP can natively read ini files using a function called `parse_ini_file()`. This function has been explicitly disabled on your server. You will need to contact your host to see if they will enable this for you (I wouldn't get your hopes up). If not, there is a small chance you might be able to configure the CMS to use a different type of configuration file (ZF supports many), but this is unlikely to be straightforward, and may not be possible at all.